# How to cast reflect.Value to its type?

Tags: reflection, go

How to cast reflect.Value to its type?

```
type Cat struct { 
    Age int
}

cat := reflect.ValueOf(obj)
fmt.Println(cat.Type()) // Cat

fmt.Println(Cat(cat).Age) // doesn't compile
fmt.Println((cat.(Cat)).Age) // same
```

Thanks!

Comment: Go has no type casting. You can't cast anything.

Comment: @GabeTucker Type conversion is not the "Go equivalent of casting." The Go equivalent of casting involves the use of `unsafe`, and it is done in a few rare circumstances.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Ok, I found it

`reflect.Value` has a function `Interface()` that converts it to `interface{}`

Comment: That converts it to interface{}. How do we convert it to the actual type?

Comment: It's not possible in Go, @Matt. You can't reinvent generics without unsafe or manual type conversions (in Go 1 at least).

Comment: concreteCat, _ := cat.Interface().(Cat) is worked for me instead of
reflect.ValueOf(cat).Interface().(Cat)

Comment: @yountae.kang I'm not sure you found out why that happens, but either way the reason why cat.Interface().(Cat) works for you is because in the above use case cat is of type reflect.Value and there is no need to convert it to the reflect.Value type again.

Answer (score 92):

```
concreteCat,_ := reflect.ValueOf(cat).Interface().(Cat)
```

see http://golang.org/doc/articles/laws_of_reflection.html
fox example

```
type MyInt int
var x MyInt = 7
v := reflect.ValueOf(x)
y := v.Interface().(float64) // y will have type float64.
fmt.Println(y)
```

Comment: That's if you actually have knowledge of the type. In the case you would like to apply kind of a blind type assertion, I'm actually not sure it is possible.

Comment: One solution seems to be to leave the `reflect.Value` as-is and simply move all your calculations to using the reflect package without hope of ever converting to back to a regular struct. You can see this in [gongular](https://github.com/mustafaakin/gongular/blob/master/handler.go#L101). Related: https://play.golang.org/p/Ok_q3lx490h

Comment: It doesn't work. `panic: interface conversion: interface {} is main.MyInt, not float64`

Comment: like @TomSawyer said it not working https://goplay.tools/snippet/-pNi3cRRDDS

Answer (score 5):

This func auto-converts types as needed. It loads a config file values into a simple struct based on struct name and fields:

```
import (
    "fmt"
    toml "github.com/pelletier/go-toml"
    "log"
    "os"
    "reflect"
)
func LoadConfig(configFileName string, configStruct interface{}) {
    defer func() {
        if r := recover(); r != nil {
            fmt.Println("LoadConfig.Recovered: ", r)
        }
    }()
    conf, err := toml.LoadFile(configFileName)
    if err == nil {
        v := reflect.ValueOf(configStruct)
        typeOfS := v.Elem().Type()
        sectionName := getTypeName(configStruct)
        for i := 0; i < v.Elem().NumField(); i++ {
            if v.Elem().Field(i).CanInterface() {
                kName := conf.Get(sectionName + "." + typeOfS.Field(i).Name)
                kValue := reflect.ValueOf(kName)
                if (kValue.IsValid()) {
                    v.Elem().Field(i).Set(kValue.Convert(typeOfS.Field(i).Type))
                }
            }
        }
    } else {
        fmt.Println("LoadConfig.Error: " + err.Error())
    }
}
```

Comment: This question should be updated to reflect that this is now the correct answer.

Answer (score 3):

Seems the only way would be to do a `switch` statement similar to (code below) (also, something like the commented line would've-been nice though doesn't work (:()):

```
func valuesFromStruct (rawV interface{}) []interface{} {
    v := reflect.ValueOf(rawV)
    out := make([]interface{}, 0)
    for i := 0; i < v.NumField(); i += 1 {
        field := v.Field(i)
        fieldType := field.Type()
        // out = append(out, field.Interface().(reflect.PtrTo(fieldType)))
        switch (fieldType.Name()) {
        case "int64":
            out = append(out, field.Interface().(int64))
            break`enter code here`
        case "float64":
            out = append(out, field.Interface().(float64))
            break
        case "string":
            out = append(out, field.Interface().(string))
            break
        // And all your other types (here) ...
        default:
            out = append(out, field.Interface())
            break
        }
    }
    return out
}
```

Cheers!